# Priority Queues in Java

Tags: java, priority-queue

[`java.util.PriorityQueue`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) allows a [`Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to be passed at construction time. When inserting elements, they are ordered according to the priority specified by the comparator.

What happens when the priority of an element changes after it has been inserted? When does the `PriorityQueue` reorder elements? Is it possible to poll an element that does not actually have minimal priority?

Are there good implementations of a priority queue which allow efficient priority updates?

Comment: Can I ask which solution you went with? I'm having similar, but at the same time very different problem, where I need to recalculate priorities of **all entries** according to time left (Least Slack Time scheduling).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should remove the element, change it, and re-insert, since ordering occurs when it is inserted. Although it involves several steps, it <s>is efficient</s> might be good enough. (I just noticed the comment about removal being O(n).)

One problem is that it will also re-order when you remove the element, which is redundant if you are just going to re-insert it a moment later. If you implement your own priority queue from scratch, you could have an update() that skips this step, but extending Java's class won't work because you are still limited to the remove() and add() provided by the base.

Answer (score 5):

I would *expect* the `PriorityQueue` to not reorder things - and it could get very confused if it tries to do a binary search to find the right place to put any new entries.

Generally speaking I'd expect changing the priority of something already in a queue to be a bad idea, just like changing the values making up a key in a hash table.

Comment: It would be really helpful for some algorithms (e.g. Dijkstra's Algorithm) to be able to change the priority of something already in the queue.

Comment: But there'd have to be a notification of that. You could fake this up without any help from PriorityQueue by removing and re-adding the item if it changes priority.

Comment: @Jon correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe removing is O(n) for sun's implementation, so this ends up being O(n log n), whereas if you could update internally it would just be O(log n).  It would seem like the ability to force an update would be nice.

Comment: @Nalandial: Yes, you're right - it feels to me like for larger queues a tree implementation would be faster...